# ExecutorService with Hibernate transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have an executor service which handles the processing of tasks asynchronously. As part of this processing, each task invokes a service bean which I've defined as being `@Transactional`.

```
processingTasks.add(executorService.submit(() -> {

    Action action = ...
    return actionService.processAction(action, Arrays,asList());

}));
```

This service method invokes a JpaRepository method to check if a entity record exists in the database. If this repository returns a null record, then a new entity object is created, then this object is processed and saved back using the repository.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public ServiceAction processAction(Action action, List<HttpMethod> methods) {

    final Action databaseAction  = Optional.ofNullable(actionRepository.findByType(action.getType()))
        .orElseGet(() -> actionRepository.save(action));

    // processing of databaseAction

    return actionRepository.save(databaseAction);

}
```

The Action entity has a unique key constraint on the `type` field. At the moment, the application is throwing a Hibernate duplicate key exception because the transaction hasn't been flushed from the first persistence of the object.

The problem I'm having is how to manage the hibernate session in this scenario? I have tried specifying an isolation level of `READ_COMMITTED` to the method to ensure each thread doesn't dirty-read. But get errors saying that manually setting the isolation level isn't supported by JPA.

What's the ideal way to manage the hibernate transaction in this scenario, such that, each thread gets the most up-to-date data from the action table.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to either synchronise or use the database - your current approach, as you have discovered, is a race hazard. So either 1) synchronize on a common lock or 2) use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Would it be better to have a `ConcurrentHashMap` of of say `Map<ActionType, Action>` in the parent service class and have the action service do the existence check via this map instead of going to the database to do it? As i understand, the ConcurrentHashMap handles the synchronization automatically so this could potentially solve thisproblem and would be more performant also?